# Hiding / displaying content in javascript

Tags: javascript, show-hide, dom-manipulation

I am a very new web developer. I'm doin fine with HTML and CSS and im trying to learn javascript. Im very new 1 month ago I never coded a single line, and I've made 2 or 3 websites already but none are JS capable.

I know I can do this in jquery and have already, but I want to **Understand it** and I want to be able to do it in vanilla javascript.

So here it is .  I am making a simple game for practice, all it does is ask questions and change elements from display = none to display = block based on a click event to two big YES or NO buttons.

So.... this first code targeting yes_button works fine. The instructions Hide and the first questiong (Q1) appears. 
the No button does not work, and I cannot figure out why, it is essentially the same code targeting a different element.

Things I checked : 
the element id/selectors are correct 
camelCase is good,
no unclosed braces,
semi colons are good,

is the mistake in the logic somewhere?

```
window.onload = function() {

yes_button.onclick= function() {
document.getElementById("instructions").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("q1").style.display="block";

};


no_button.onClick=function() {
document.getElementById("instructions").style.display="none";   
document.getElementById("nointro").style.display="block";

};



};
```

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the HTML/DOM structure, without knowing what `yes_button` and `no_button` are, etc. The actual code shown is fine as far as it goes, so...

Comment: onClick should be onclick. Javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: Luis, I personally condone your use of "wanna". One of my favorite non-words. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the window.onload function call. You can place your JavaScript imports just before the closing  tag so the dom is ready before you attempt to click on the button.

Your JavaScript Events should look like this:

```
document.getElementById("yes_button").onclick = function(){

             document.getElementById("instructions").style.display= "none";
             document.getElementById("q1").style.display = "block";

};


document.getElementById("no_button").onclick = function(){

            document.getElementById("instructions").style.display="none";   
            document.getElementById("nointro").style.display="block";


};
```

Comment: Not a problem, I hope your game development goes well.